# Split cell content into multiple separate rows in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Suppose in A1 cell I have some comma separated letters.

```
content(A1 cell) = A, W, L, F
```

I would like to the following result:

```
content(A2 cell) = A
content(A3 cell) = W
content(A4 cell) = L
content(A5 cell) = F
```

However if I type in A1 cell the following:

```
content(A1 cell) = S, E, U, F, H, R, T
```

I would like to be the result:

```
content(A2 cell) = S
content(A3 cell) = E
content(A4 cell) = U
content(A5 cell) = F
content(A6 cell) = H
content(A7 cell) = R
content(A8 cell) = T
```

Is there a function which will do this job? For example I would like to a function formula in B1 cell, which checks the content of A1 cell and its outputs will be the above results.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: I can do it with Python, although it can probably also be done with VBA. Perhaps instead of typing those Comma Separated values into Excel, you could put them into a text file with a .CSV extension and import it?

Comment: I can't think of an easy way of doing this in a single step but it feels like you could use Excel's built in Text to Columns feature then use Copy> Paste Special>Transpose to get into into rows depending on the volume of data

Comment: On the DATA tab you can use "Text to Columns" to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

formula

```
=INDEX(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,", ",""),ROW($A$1:INDIRECT("a"&LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,", ","")))),1),ROWS($A$1:A1))
```

Comment: to remove error (#REF!) , add iferror function . something like :        IFERROR(aboveformula,"")

Comment: A commentary would have been useful

Answer (score 0):

## Split Cell Into Rows

Functions do not work in the way you described the possible functionality in your question, but here is a 'similar' **VBA** solution using the **Worksheet Change Event**.

### Highlights

- In `Worksheet_Change` you can choose (provide) the **Split Cell Range
  Address** containing the delimited data (`cStrCell`) and the **Split
  Delimiter** (`cStrDel`).
- When changing the data in the **Split Cell Range**, the solution will
  copy the delimited data below the **Split Cell Range** into the
  **Split Data Range** and delete all data below.
- The change of any cell in the **Split Data Range** is not possible.

[image]

Copy the following code to the desired **sheet code** window e.g. Sheet1(Code).

### The Code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const cStrCell As String = "A1"   ' Split Cell Range Address
    Const cStrDel As String = ","     ' Split Delimiter

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' Check if changed cell range is contained in Split Range.
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range(cStrCell).Resize(UBound(Split( _
            Range(cStrCell), cStrDel)) + 2)) Is Nothing Then

        On Error GoTo ProcedureExit

        ' Check if changed cell range address
        ' is equal to Split Cell Range Address.
        If Target.Address = Range(cStrCell).Address Then
            ' Clear contents of data below Split Range.
            Range(Range(cStrCell).Offset(1), Cells(Rows.Count, _
                    Range(cStrCell).Column).End(xlUp)).ClearContents
        End If

        ' Fill Split Range with Split Data
        ' i.e. copy Split Data below Split Cell Range.
        SplitToRows Range(cStrCell), cStrDel

    End If

ProcedureExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Sub SplitToRows(SplitCellRange As Range, Optional Delimiter As String = ",")

    Dim vntS As Variant   ' Source Array
    Dim vntT As Variant   ' Target Array
    Dim i As Long         ' Arrays Row Counter

    ' Split first cell in SplitCellRange by Delimiter into Source Array.
    vntS = Split(SplitCellRange.Cells(1, 1), Delimiter)

    ' Resize 2D one-based Target Array.
    ReDim vntT(1 To UBound(vntS) + 1, 1 To 1)

    ' Trim and copy from Source to Target Array.
    For i = 0 To UBound(vntS)
        vntT(i + 1, 1) = Trim(vntS(i))
    Next

    ' Copy Target Array to Target Range below SplitCellRange.
    SplitCellRange.Cells(1, 1).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(vntT)) = vntT

End Sub
```

Comment: Dear All. Thank you very much your answers. The marked answer is more easier for me.